# Check mxd has been saved prior to running python code

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, mxd

Is it possible to check whether an mxd has any unsaved changes prior to running the main code of a python script? I'm aware I can use the document name:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
mapPath = mxd.filePath  
fileName = os.path.basename(mapPath)
```

If mapPath is blank, the document has not been saved. But how can I repeat this check for unsaved changes once the document has been saved in the past?

Comment: Compare date saved with now

Comment: Spot on @FelixIP, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python and calculate the timedelta https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html there isn't a python 'is dirty' http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004200000175000000 flag for a MXD so that's the best you're going to get.

Comment: Any particular changes you are looking to check for?

Comment: Are you wanting to check if it has unsaved changes, or just save it?

Comment: I'm not looking for any particular changes. Just want to make sure the user has saved the document before they run my scripts. FelixIP's suggestion of checking save dates sounds like it should work.

Comment: Why don't you just save the mxd as a first step in your script?

Comment: We're trying to encourage people to save their work often. If the scripts save, I reckon people will become lazy!